# building targets according to a build matrix

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to create builds as specified by `BUILDS` (which essentially is a flattened build matrix). Creating the targets is quite straight forward - but inside the target I'd need to parse the path to figure out the `OS` and `ARCH`. There must be a better way.

```
BUILDS=\
  darwin-amd64  \
  linux-386     \
  linux-amd64   \
  linux-arm     \
  linux-arm64   \
  windows-386   \
  windows-amd64 \

DISTS=$(BUILDS:%=dist/$(NAME)-%-$(VERSION).tgz)

dist:
  @mkdir -p dist

$(DISTS): dist
  @echo "building: $@"
  @touch $@
```

What's a good approach to get access to the `OS` and `ARCH` inside the `$(DISTS)` target?

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at [these functions for string matching/dissecting](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt#call-glob-matchstringpattern).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no great answer to this.  It's also not clear what you want to do with `OS` and `ARCH`; it makes a difference if you want them to be makefile variables or shell variables.

Here's one possible solution:

```
$(DISTS): OS = $(word 1,$(subst -, ,$*))
$(DISTS): ARCH = $(word 2,$(subst -, ,$*))

$(DISTS): dist/$(NAME)-%-$(VERSION).tgz: dist
        @echo "building: $@"
        @echo "OS = $(OS)"
        @echo "ARCH = $(ARCH)"
        @touch $@
```

(not tested).  Basically this uses a static pattern rule which allows make to set the `$*` automatic variable to the part of the target which matches the pattern.  Then, we use the target-specific variable feature to set `OS` and `ARCH`

Comment: In the end I need them to pass to the compiler.

Comment: Wow - that indeed works. I extracted the pattern into a variable (which surprisingly works) to make it more DRY.